# Creating aspect the retrieves object from method and return another object

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to write an aspect (in Spring) which taking the input params from a method in my package do some manipulation and return to that method a result.

Is that possible?

For example:

```
public MyClass {

 Public void execute (Object object)
  {
     //doSomeLogic with the returned object from the aspect
  }
}

@Aspect
public class ExecutionAspect {




@Before(// any idea?)
        public void getArgument(JoinPoint joinPoint) {


         Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
         for (Object signatureArg: signatureArgs) {
             MyObject myObject=(MyObject)signatureArg;
             //do some manipulation on myObject
}
                  //Now how do I return the object to the intercepted method?


    }
```

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to change the return value, you will have to use an `@Around` advice.

```
@Aspect
public class AroundExample {

  @Around("some.pointcut()")
  public Object doSomeStuff(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs(); // change the args if you want to
    Object retVal = pjp.proceed(args); // run the actual method (or don't)
    return retVal; // return the return value (or something else)
  }

}
```

The mechanism is described here: [Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) > [AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) > [Around Advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice)

Comment: Your 3 lines summarises the complete @Around functionality way better than the spring manual does. +1. Many thanks.

Comment: @CaptainHackSparrow I know. The only reasonable reference I know of is Ramnivas Laddad's book [AspectJ in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/aspectj-in-action-second-edition). While focussing on "real" AspectJ, it also has several chapters on Spring AOP.